# how to click an svg element onclick of a div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an svg Rect.Onclick of a div I need to click the svg rect.
Here I have attached the code

```
<div id="demo" class="demo">click here</div>
<p id="demo1"></p>  
<svg width="50" height="50" id="svgid">
  <rect width="50" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

Script code is

```
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function()
{
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    $('#svgid').click(function()
    {
       alert("clicked");

    });
});
</script>
```

Here Hello World is  showing on click of demo div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this so when you click on the text, the alert is run.

I moved the alert outside the handler as otherwise you'd get one alert the first time you click on the text then two alerts the second time and so on.

```js
$('#svgid').click(function()
    {
       alert("clicked");

    });
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click",     function()
{
  document.getElementById("svgid").dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" class="demo">click here</div>
<p id="demo1"></p>  
<svg width="50" height="50" id="svgid">
  <rect width="50" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to implement this, first, you can add `onclick="clicked()"` on to the html element, then in javascript you just need to define the function

```
<script>
  function clicked_stv(){
    alert('it happened');
  };
</script>
```

Alternatively, if you are using jquery,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#svgid').click(function() {
    alert('It happened');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" class="demo">click here</div>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<svg width="50" height="50" id="svgid">
    <rect width="50" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: When I click on the **click here** text, nothing happens. The question states: "Onclick of a div I need to click the svg rect"